# How to fetch the title of a module in Joomla

Tags: joomla, module, joomla-module

I have created a *module* that lists out the specific list of *articles*. I could fetch the parameter of the *module* using `$params` . . But I couldn't fetch the *title* of the *module*.
Can anybody help me with this ? ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is a normal PHP function and so can use any regular PHP code. One common example is to use an if statement to check the value of $module->showtitle, and then include the title or not accordingly:

```
 <?php
 if ($module->showtitle) 
   {
       echo '<h2>' .$module->title .'</h2>';
   }
 ?>
```

more information read it

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=469&t=289641